# Flash cs6 1071 error

Tags: flash, countdowntimer

Trying to get this code working in Flash AS3 but keep getting this error:

1071: Syntax error: expected a definition keyword (such as function) after attribute function, not updateTimer.

```
    var countdownTimer:Timer = new Timer (1000);
    counterTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.Timer, updateTimer);
    countdownTimer.Start();

    Function updateTimer(Event:TimerEvent):void{
        var Today:Date = new Date();
        var year = Today.getFullYear();
        var dtsBegin:Date = new Date(year, 2, 31); 
        var dtsEnd:Date = new Date(year, 9, 27);
        if((today >= dtsBegin) && (today <= dtsEnd)){
            Today.minutes -= 0;
        }
        else{
            Today.minutes += 60;
        }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of things are case sensitive in AS3.

- the keyword function is lower case
- "Today" is different then "today"
- The Timer property in TimerEvent is in all cap: "TimerEvent.Timer" doesn't exist
- Missing the closing brace for your function
- missing the imports for Timer and TimerEvent
- you have 'counterTimer' when I think you meant 'countdownTimer'
- the start() method call should be lowercase: Timer.Start() doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the first time i've ever used this program and everything you pointed out helped me :) cheers